# Letting HTML forms make use of JSON APIs

Tags: javascript, html, forms, node.js, api

So, I've spent a lot of time writing a cool RESTful API. To simplify, one can create a new user by performing a `POST` request to `/users`.

Great, huh? But now my HTML form wants to create a user. All of its elements are identical to the arguments that need to be passed to `/users`. Therefore, it seems to make a lot of sense for the `form` to make full use of this excellent API.

My form resides on `/register.html`. It's properties are now: `action="/users" method="post"`. Great integration with my API right out-of-the-box!

The problem? My RESTful API will respond in JSON, and my form cannot deal with this response. For example, when an invalid e-mail address is passed, the returned body may be `{"error": 400, "msg": "The given email address is invalid."}`. Instead, `register.html` should receive this message and display an appropriate message while allowing the user to fix the input mistake.

An obvious solution would be to not send the form at all, and instead use AJAX to interact with the API based on the inputs' values. However, this is far from ideal because the form would be useless for those without Javascript.

Is there any other approach that I can consider? Or should I not couple form input with my APIs?

I don't think it matters much, but I'm working with Node.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a dual-mode API: accept JSON and form-data input, emit JSON and HTML (or HTML fragments) back in response.

HTML fragments start making sense in context of seamless iframes; In the mean time that approach would still take javascript on the client. Full HTML is the classic web -- there's nothing preventing your resources from being both HTML and JSON represented.

The `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers are your friend. Don't for a moment confuse the URL of your resource with its representation with the resource itself. Those are three separate things. Yes, it's messy sometimes. So's the world!

Comment: Seems interesting, but wouldn't it be very confusing for the user to see `/api/v1/users` in his address bar? He'd probably be expecting `/register.html`.

Comment: Another problem with resolving input issues on an address different from the original address `register.html` is that even though this is essentially the same page the address is very different. This is frowned upon by search engines and will mess up site analytics.

Comment: And to continue.. if the user were to refresh the page (navigate to the same address), the browser would send a GET request to `/api/v1/users`, which has a completely different meaning. This request would retrieve all users, something that the user did not expect.